# Is a full app rebuild expected behaviour when changing url in browser when using go_router?

Tags: flutter, flutter-go-router

I am using the `go_router` package (13.0.0) for navigation in my Flutter web app. When I manually edit the url in the browser it rebuilds the entire flutter app (i.e right from the very first line in `main()`.

Is this expected behaviour?